# Auto Increment a field value every time a doc is updated in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, versioning, auto-increment

**This is payload**

```
 {
  "videourl": "*****",
"name": "ABCqq",
"description": "AAAnb",
"tags": "#AAAzx",
"uploadedtime": "2020-02-24T05:48:37.527Z",
"uploadedby": "Dr AAAgh",
"thumbnail": "http://",
"duration": "5:32",
"postedby": "AAAdf",
"doctorimage": "AAA12",
"doctorname": "nnn",
}
```

**Result in the form**

```
{"_index": "rwe",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "8wEed3ABcYN_H8khP4hB",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "videourl": "*****",
    "name": "ABCqq",
    "description": "AAAnb",
    "tags": "#AAAzx",
    "uploadedtime": "2020-02-24T05:48:37.527Z",
    "uploadedby": "Dr AAAgh",
    "thumbnail": "http://",
    "duration": "5:32",
    "postedby": "AAAdf",
    "doctorimage": "AAA12",
    "doctorname": "nnn"
}
}
```

This is a document where I want to increment the count value of the field every time when this doc gets updated.
    we have to add new field which has the name **counter_value**.

**Expected Resultt**

```
{"_index": "rwe",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "8wEed3ABcYN_H8khP4hB",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "videourl": "*****",
    "name": "ABCqq",
    "description": "AAAnb",
    "tags": "#AAAzx",
    "uploadedtime": "2020-02-24T05:48:37.527Z",
    "uploadedby": "Dr AAAgh",
    "thumbnail": "http://",
    "duration": "5:32",
    "postedby": "AAAdf",
    "doctorimage": "AAA12",
    "doctorname": "nnn",
    "counter_value": 1
}
}
```

Comment: How do you index your document? Can you explain your process?

Comment: we have only 1 index =  'rwe' and type = '_doc'

Comment: I'm asking about your process. How do you index documents?

Comment: we have added simple fields(videourl, name, description etc..) as payload

Answer (score 1):

You can just increment the counter via scripting, see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/increment-counter-if-document-already-exists/138604/4) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html). However, elastic already has a version field. Depending on your usecase, it might be enough to add the `version` parameter to your query, as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-version):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/rwe/_search?version=true'
```